# Flutter - How to rotate shadow with object?

Tags: flutter, animation, rotation, containers

[image]

So I have an object that rotates along the Y axis. I have used a container with box shadow to cast the shadow of the object.

No I have a container that rotates but it kind of loses its width in the center (if you know how transform works)... How can I rotate the container without it losing its width throughout the rotation.

[image]

```
class _TestState extends State<Test> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
 late final AnimationController _controller;
 @override
 void initState() {
  _controller = AnimationController(
    vsync: this,
    duration: Duration(seconds: 25),
  )..repeat();
  super.initState();
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
 double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('3D Demo'),
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0, vertical: 0),
      // width: double.infinity,
      // height: double.infinity,

      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          // stops: [0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9],
          colors: [Colors.black, Colors.black],
        ),
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Divider(),
          Divider(),


          SizedBox(
            height: screenHeight * 0.5,
            child: Stack(
              children: [


                Center(
                  child: AnimatedBuilder(
                    animation: _controller,
                    builder: (_, child) {
                      return Transform(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        transform: Matrix4.identity()
                          ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.001)
                          //..rotateX(0.01 * _offset.dy)
                          //   ..rotateY(0.01 * _offset.dx),
                          // alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                          ..rotateY(
                            _controller.value * (-math.pi),
                          ),
                        // ..rotateZ(
                        //   math.pi *
                        //       2 *
                        //       _controller
                        //           .value, //change 0 to any value to rotate z Axis
                        // ),
                        child: child,
                      );
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      child: AnimatedContainer(
                        //transform: Matrix4.skewX(10),
                        height: 100,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 5000),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),

                            boxShadow:

                                [
                              BoxShadow(
                                color: Colors.yellow.withOpacity(0.6),
                                spreadRadius: 1,
                                blurRadius: 16,
                                offset: const Offset(-0, 0),
                              ),

                            ]
                            
                            ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
   ),
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the shadow to look like it has a Z-dimension?

Comment: Yes... It has to be flat to the ground, so it should have a Z direction, and then it should rotate along the Y Axis.

Comment: How big of a Z-axis do you want? Because shadows don't have Z-axes IRL, obviously. If you are just trying to mask the brief moment of invisibility, you can use a hacky solution involving an overlay. What exactly do you mean by "losing its width?"

Comment: About 40-50 (roughly the same size as the current height). Currently it looks like a vertical container, I want it to look like a horizontal one; so the current height would become its length across Z axis and height (Y axis) would be lesser.
Losing its width means as you can see in the gif, when the container becomes exactly perpendicular to the screen it disappears for a moment. A shadow won't disappear like that. Imagine a Vehicle rotating along the Y axis, how its shadow would rotate with it; that's what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want. Paste the following code into [DartPad](https://www.dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true) and you can see that it's just a matter of adding more rotations. Hopefully someone can show me a more efficient way of doing the transformations, but this works.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Test(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController _controller;

  bool isAnimating = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 10),
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('3D Demo'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: _controller,
          builder: (_, child) {
            return Transform(
              alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
              transform: Matrix4.identity()
                ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.002)
                ..rotateY(0.5 * -math.pi)
                ..rotateZ(-0.1 * math.pi)
                ..rotateY((_controller.value - 0.5) * -math.pi)
                ..rotateX(0.5 * math.pi),
              child: child,
            );
          },
          child: Container(
            height: 100,
            width: 200,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          isAnimating ? _controller.stop() : _controller.repeat();
          setState(() {
            isAnimating = !isAnimating;
          });
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Genius! Could you tell me if I can get the rotation to start at a particular position? As in, the rectangle(length) should be kind of perpendicular to the screen when it is rendered; and then it should start rotating from that position....

Comment: @whoadityanawandar I updated my answer with the functionality you described. Slightly changed the controller value (you could swap container dimensions instead) and added stop/start button

Comment: @PatrikMahomes Thanks man, I have posted another question, can you take a look please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69356571/flutter-blurradius-strange-behaviour