# Flutter - blurRadius strange behaviour

Tags: flutter, animation, containers, blur

So I have a rotating container

[image]

Here is the working code:

```
@override
void initState() {
   _controller = AnimationController(
   vsync: this,
   duration: Duration(seconds: 32),
 )..repeat();
  super.initState();
 }

....

  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
  double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
   return Container(
    child: Column(
     children: <Widget>[
      SizedBox(
        height: screenHeight,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [

              ],
            ),
            Divider(),
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Center(
                  child: AnimatedBuilder(
                    animation: _controller,
                    builder: (_, child) {
                      return Transform(
                        alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                        transform: Matrix4.identity()
                          ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.002)
                          ..rotateY(0.5 * -math.pi)
                          ..rotateZ(-0.1 * math.pi)
                          ..rotateY((_controller.value - 0.6) * -math.pi)
                          ..rotateX(0.5 * math.pi),
                        child: child,
                      );
                    },

                    child: Container(

                      //color: Colors.yellow.withOpacity(0.5),
                      height: 300,
                      width: 200,

                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.yellow.withOpacity(0.5),
                           spreadRadius: 40,

         //UNCOMMENTING THIS LINE CAUSES STRANGE BEHAVIOUR
                            //blurRadius: 50,
                            //offset: const Offset(0, 0),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    //),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 170,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
 );
}
```

However, when I uncomment the blurRadius line of code, it behaves strangely. Look how the container kind of gets distorted when it comes perpendicular to the screen.

[image]

I want it to be consistently blurred. This is something strange.

Comment: share the actual result you want to achieve.

Comment: I just want the container to be rotating as in the first image, but blurred.

Comment: then your commented line is blurring the container. for rotating where are your starting your animation ?

Comment: Yes the commented line helps in blurring the container but it doesn't work. The blurring is not consistent. See the 2nd image please. The container loses its shape in the middle. I have added the code where I start the animation, please check.

Comment: strange. I think blur only work with the x-y values. Why not to use a blur rectangle assets ?

Comment: I commented the entry point function, and the Animation is working fine along with the blur effect but it has a little bit dimension issue, which I think is relativity visual issue.

Comment: What is blur rectangle assets?

Comment: @FaiiziiAwan Please post your comment as answer, I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the reasons behind it but removing the line `..setEntry(3, 2, 0.002)` will remove the issues. However, there is a slight dimension issue during the animation which I thinks because of relativity. With the above line, it seems like animation decrease the blur effect with the increase of animation completion factor and reset to provided value when it reaches the starting point of animation.

Answer (score 1):

Shadows are very expensive for Flutter to draw, so it's bad to animate them like this because Flutter has to keep repainting the shadow. Since the shadow is also causing your transform problem, you should try to make the shadow you want in GIMP/Adobe or screenshot it in flutter, then add it to your project.

You should have an assets or images folder in your project directory, i.e, `YOUR_FLUTTER_PROJECT/images`. Put the shadow image in there.

Then, in the `pubspec.yaml` file, there should be a field for your assets. Add the path to the shadow file there, e.g.:

```
assets:
  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
  - images/YOUR_SHADOW_FILE
```

Run `flutter pub get`

In your code, replace your `Container` with this:

```
Image.asset('images/YOUR_SHADOW_FILE', height: 300, width: 200),
```

I haven't tested it, but I reckon it should still work.

Comment: And then rotate the shadow in place of the container ??

Comment: @whoadityanawandar yes, rotate the picture of your shadow instead of the Container

Comment: Will try and see if it works the way I want it to